# Terran vs Zerg builds

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-terran, sc2-build-order

**What's an aggressive Terran strategy that's effective against Zerg players?**

I'm really curious about attacking Zerg early. Since I'm fairly new to SC2 the only "real" build/strategy I know is 1-1-1 in TvP. Here I get cloaked banshees as fast as possible and attack the Protoss mineral line or early expansion. I'd like to know a similar strategy againt Zerg.

Answer (score 8):

[Reactor Hellion Expand](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Reactor_Hellion_Expand_%28vs._Zerg%29) is the standard TvZ build right now. You open with a couple of quick Hellions and use them to harass, deny creep spread, force Zergling production, and gain map control. This allows you to quickly take your natural expansion and transition in whatever direction you'd like. It's not very aggressive but learning all-in builds without having fundamentals behind them is a waste of time.

Comment: +1, especially for the last sentence. Reactor Hellion is very good vs. Zerg. If opponent doesn't get lots of queens or roaches, Hellions can not only gain map-control but also do huge damage to the mineral line (either by forcing a way up the ramp or by dropping via medivac). Cloaked banshee is also a common addition to Hellion openings.

Answer (score 6):

The best build in TvZ in my opinion is a build used by Polt. The goal is to be very aggressive once you get your medivacs and stim. Then you can expand once more and add tanks and ghosts to your army.

The build :

- Open reactor hellion expand and add two more barracks
- Research stim and combat shields while producing marauders off one rax and marines one others
- Tech to medivacs and start upgrades (double ebay is great)
- Attack front while dropping back (or use "elevator tricks" to enter the main directly)

If this doesn't give you the win (and it will 75% of time)

- Continue on upgrades. Add more barracks (3 rax/reactor per mining base is a good count)
- Add 3rd base, one more factory and one more starport and start tank production
- Slowly push through the map with tanks and bioball while dropping expos
- Add Ghosts to snipe/EMP infestors

Important things to note :

- Standard muta timing off two base is around 10 minutes. Be sure your first attack comes right before this timing (around 9 - 9:30 is fine). Don't forget to build some turrets in your main and natural to protect SCVs and production.
- Best answer to ling/infestor style is to drop EVERYWHERE
- Best answer to mutas/ling/banes is to slowly push with tanks
- Never leave tanks alone, never unsiege all tanks at once
- Make supply depot wall at your natural entrance and at you third entrance
- 4 marines in a bunker can save a base from a lings runby
- Except in the super early game (food < 50) always have depots building. The rule of thumb is to build as many depots at once you have bases and you'll never get supply blocked.
- Scan the zerg tech every 5 minutes or so and attack when you see lair morphing (stim + medivacs) and when you see hive morphing (same with tanks and better upgrades).
- When you see hive morphing and he has spire, switch to viking production

Comment: There seems to be something missing at the end of your answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can also go 2 Rax pressure. Build your Rax at 11 and 13 supply and push when your second Marine pops out with 3 SCVs and 2 Marines.

If they are expanding you build two bunkers so at least one survives.

Once your bunker is full with 3-4 Marines stop reinforcing and expand. Sometimes you are able to kill the expansion other times you are overrun by 10 zerglings. Either way you have done considerable damage as you delay your SCV production only for your 11 / 13 Rax but the Zerg has to make a ton of Lings and Drones just to trow them at your Bunker.

If you see a ton of Zerglings try to salvage your bunker and stutter step your Marines back until they die.

Build a new bunker at your expansion to be save from all ins.

MarineKingPrime and MakaPrime use this strategy a lot.

This build needs a lot of good micro.

Comment: MKP almost exclusively uses 11/11 rax for 2rax pressure. Going with 11/13 is too slow to scare the Zerg on newer maps because the rush distances have increased by a good bit compared to early SC2 maps.